How to add an asset file that can be accessed via a path and not via the rootbundle (Flutter)
I want to be able to have a file assets/someFile.txt and add this to the app in a way that the file is already on the filesystem ready to be accessed. I don't want it to be in the rootbundle (a.k.a. asset archive) of Flutter.
// This is what I want to be able to do.
String filePath = '${await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()}/someFile.txt';  
File myFile = File(filePath);

// Not this
// Read the file from the rootbundle
String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/someFile.txt');
// create a file on the filesystem and write the data to it.

The reason why I want this, is because I am using a library (Objectbox) that requires a file that has my data. Having a file ready to go straight away would be better than having to first read one from the assetbundle, create a file and then write the data to it.
Is there a way to specify this to Flutter that a certain asset should just be put in the app as a file and not be included in the rootbundle?

Conclusion  Flutter doesn't directly support placing assets on the filesystem outside of the rootBundle.
If your asset files are too large, downloading them from a file server is a practical solution. This approach reduces the app package size and allows for dynamic updates.
